# How to pass php array in input type hidden in html form

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to pass my php array in my form input type as hidden.i have tried  many times but it is giving me an array (key=>value,key=>value) in my input form.

This is my php code have a array.

```
 $my_arr = array();
 $my_arr['key']="value";
```

This is my html code

```
 <form method="post" action="next.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="my_form_data" value="<?php print_r($my_arr) ?>">
 <button name="submit_btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any one please help me to pass php array in my input hidden element and how to get it in next page.

Comment: i have limit to pass one hidden element only @VimalS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can try this:

```
<form method="post" action="next.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="my_form_data" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(serialize($my_arr)) ?>">
 <button name="submit_btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in `next.php` you unserialize to get the PHP data structure back:

```
<?php
$my_arr = unserialize($_POST["my_form_data"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to make json as string by `json_encode` and then decode at the time of retrieve by `json_decode`,

```
<form method="post" action="next.php">
<input type="hidden" name="my_form_data" value="<?php echo json_encode($my_arr); ?>">
<button name="submit_btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$hiddenvariable=array("apple","banana","cat");
foreach($hiddenvariable as $value)
{
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="my_form_data[]" value="'. $value. '">';
}
```

Making an array first then extracting an each elements using foreach and passing those values into hidden value.

Comment: This is something same as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-array-using-html-form-hidden-element

Comment: I have just modified the code according to his need mate I haven't searched on stackoverflow and read all those duplicate answers. Gave him answer according to this need :)

Comment: My positive vote to this answer! It's simple and don't need changes in the root form. good head!
Very usefull if you have a form with select multiple and link in the results to a profile, and a back button to the form, because this answer make the array like a multiple select.

Answer (score 0):

Use `my_form_data[]` in name

```
<form method="post" action="next.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="my_form_data" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($my_arr));?>">
</form>
```

Comment: @bharat-savani  I changed my answer