# html php POSTing javascript integer array

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am extending an internal web application project written with HTML, PHP and pure javascript. I want to POST a *javascript integer array*, alongside with other inputs, into another PHP file for further processing.

A very simplified version of what I would like to achieve is like this:

form.php

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
    <!-- along with other inputs -->
    <input type="hidden" id="ints" name="ints">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
<script>
    var ints = [2,4,6];
    document.getElementsByName("ints").value=ints;
</script>
```

post.php

```
if (isset($_POST['ints'])){
    var_dump($_POST['ints']); //expected an array of numbers or strings
}else{
    echo "not POSTed";
}
```

But it seems that I failed to POST it. I have tried making the input field `ints` as `ints[]` and tried using `getElementById`. The best I have got is a string "2,4,6", and I may have done this using `explode()` in PHP, but I would like to know if there are better options.

I want to stick with pure javascript, but if it is not possible, I may try other stuffs like jQuery. Any hints and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Array Using Html Form Hidden Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-array-using-html-form-hidden-element)

Comment: you should not send array in input field. Send value with `,` comma separated

Comment: Not so much of duplicate. That link wants to post a PHP array in my understanding.
W-well, I just want to know if there is a cleaner way to make this work, maybe...

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
document.getElementsByName("ints").value=ints;
```

... with this:

```
document.getElementsByName("ints")[0].setAttribute("value", ints);
```

There doesn't seem to be a `value` property on the node list returned by `getElementsByName()` which works the way you're trying to use it in your code above. Note that if the correct element isn't the first (maybe only) match for `getElementsByName()`, you'll have to change the index above, or use another means of selecting the element, like a class.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the input is string. you should pass the ints array using a serialized JSON array using either ajax or XmlHttpRequest (better)

```
submit.onclick = function(){

   ints = [1,2,3];

   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);

   request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

   request.send({
      ints : ints
   });

}
```