# Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I pass values through form action field in CodeIgniter framework?

First, I tried to add PHP variable direct to the form action field, that I  am attaching below

```
<form class="col s12" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Welcome/forgotpass/').$res; ?>" method="post">
```

`$res` is an array. That is defined below

```
$res=array('id'=>$h['id'],'username'=>$h['username'],'usertype'=>$h['usertype']);
```

`$h` is defined in the controller

```
$res['h'] = $this->forgotpassword->forgotpassword();
```

`$this->load->view('forgotpassword1',$res);`

the `h` is read in the view array `$res` and I want to pass this array through form action and that would be read in the controller.

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to accomplish??

Comment: You can Just create a Hidden input field and you can Just echo the Values in the `value`attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Array Using Html Form Hidden Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-array-using-html-form-hidden-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a few things:

Turn the variables into a string `$str` where `$str = 'id=this&username=that'` and in your action `<?php echo base_url('index.php/Welcome/forgotpass/') . '?' . $str; ?>` and fetch the individual variables via `$this->input->get('username')` .etc.

OR

Turn each into a hidden input:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
foreach ($res as $field_name => $field_value) {
    echo form_hidden($field_name, $field_value);
}
```

and fetch the individual variables via `$this->input->post('username')`

OR

**Send the user a recovery key:**

Have the user enter a unique identifier such as their username or name and post that to the forgotten password controller which will then get the user's email in a fashion like:

`$this->db->select('email')->where('username', $this->input->post('username'))->get('users')->row()->email;`

and store a hashed long value in your database in the users row (let's call it `recovery_key`) which you send to the user using the email you just got from the unique identifier. When the user gets the email it contains a link like `somewebsite.com/pass_recovery/some_recovery_key` and with that they can reset their password as *only* they have the unique hash.

On the recovery page simply see if a hashed value like that exists in the database, if it does, it exists to a single user - the user that is trying to recover their password.

Check out Ion_Auth, they do this well.

Comment: Thank you for you answer