# PHP, Send Array with 2 fields as input hidden through Form

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array $newArray, it has been built inside of a POST form, so I want to send the whole array in a INPUT as hidden:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day1to7] => 1
            [timeHHMM] => 10:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day1to7] => 1
            [timeHHMM] => 11:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day1to7] => 1
            [timeHHMM] => 12:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day1to7] => 5
            [timeHHMM] => 14:00
        )

)
```

Could you please help me to know how shall I write it in INPUT?

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="newArraySend" value="'. $newArray[day1to7]['timeHHMM'] . '">';  -> this is my wrong try
```

And also, please let me know how could I receive it?

```
$newArrayReceived = $_POST['newArraySend']; ->this also is wrong I think
```

Thank you very much in advance,
Felipe

Comment: what you want to pass with your hidden input? the whole array in your case 4 element or just one element with `day1to7` and `timeHHMM`

Comment: HI Being Sunny, I want to pass the whole array.

Comment: There is many ways but the easier and the most secure would be to store it in `$_SESSION` if you want to avoid it to be edited and having to re-validate the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Array Using Html Form Hidden Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-array-using-html-form-hidden-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the specific question; you could loop and add the hidden inputs:

```
foreach($newArray as $key => $val) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="newArraySend['.$key.'][day1to7]" value="'.$val['day1to7'].'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="newArraySend['.$key.'][timeHHMM]" value="'.$val['timeHHMM'].'">';
}
```

Then the receiving PHP should use `$_POST['newArraySend']` just as you would the original array.

Or just encode the entire array:

```
$val = htmlentities(json_encode($newArray));
echo '<input type="hidden" name="newArraySend" value="'.$val.'">';
```

Then decode on the receiving end:

```
$result = json_decode(html_entity_decode($_POST['newArraySend']), true);
```

But really this might be better handled with a session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['newArray'] = $newArray;
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
session_start();
$result = $_SESSION['newArray'];
```

Comment: Thank you AbraCadaver, second option for me is the best ! :)

Comment: NP, added an alternative.

Comment: Interesting, thank you so much again :) 
By the way, just there is one "dot" missing in "Or just encode the entire array" concatenating $val.
:) Thanks again