# I want to know the correct syntax of declaring multiple variables in php with small changes like mentioned below

Tags: php, variables, declaration

```
$str='abcde';//for sub-question numbers
    for ($i=1; $i <=10 ; $i++) {//i loop is for question numbers 1 to 10
        for ($j=0; $j<5 ; $j++) {//j loop is for sub-questions from a to e
            $q{$i}{$str[$j]}=$_POST['q{$i}{$str[j]}'];//not sure about this part
        }
    }
```

Here the main idea is to create 50 variables from q1a,q1b,... till q10d,q10e.

Comment: How about using an array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-array-using-html-form-hidden-element (Ignore the part about hidden...)

Comment: Don't do it.  Array...

Comment: Rather redesign the form (`…name="q[1][a]"`) to make it easier to work with..

Comment: Its a bad idea, 1. you could create a variable that already exists and overwrite its value silently. 2. it makes debugging and reading the code a pain in the ... etc.  And its done this way `${'p'.$i.$str[$j]}` (`$p0a, $p1a` .. etc)  but again don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what the values of those variables will be, but here is how to create an array with those variable names in them.

```html
$questions = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); //questions
$subQuestions = array('a','b','c','d','e');  //sub-question

$allQuestions = array();
foreach($questions as $question) {//loop the questions
    foreach($subQuestions as $subQ) {//loop the sub questions
        // I'm not clear what you're trying to do here -> $q{$i}{$str[$j]}=$_POST['q{$i}{$str[j]}'];//not sure about this part
        $allQuestions["q" . $question . $subQ] = "I'm an empty value right now"; //what value goes here?
    }
}
var_dump($allQuestions);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do something like this

```
$values = array("q1a", "q1b", "q1c", "q1d", "q1e", "q2a", "q2b", "q2c", "q2d", "q2e");
for($i=;$i<$sizeof($values);$i++)
{
$values[$i] = $_POST['q{$i}{$str[j]}'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your POST vars which you want to grab are prepended with `q` then just filter them with [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Then you can use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), but tbh, you should just use the array.

```
<?php
$_POST = [
    'q1' => 'baz',
    'foo' => 'bar',
];

$q = array_filter($_POST, function($k) {
    return substr($k, 0, 1) === 'q';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

extract($q);

// filtered array
print_r($q);

// extract'ed
echo $q1;
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [q1] => baz
)
baz
```

https://3v4l.org/rvMR6