# Passing all values into one variable then split them

Tags: php, forms, session

Hi so for the website I am designing I have been asked to use mal's eCommerce for the payment gateway. I have been trying to set up the remote call function they have so that once a purchase has been made it will make a call back to my website to run a script and sen email confirmation of their order.

This however has proved extremely frustrating as the session variables I have stored do not get passed through with the remote call, only certain values that they allow.

I tried storing them all in an array and putting them in one of the values I can change called sd:

```
$cart =array($_SESSION["date"], $_SESSION["name"], $_SESSION["email"], $_SESSION["number"], $_SESSION["address"], $_SESSION["town"], $_SESSION["postcode"],
$_SESSION["county"], $_SESSION["cake_type"], $_SESSION["collection"], $_SESSION["icingColour"], $_SESSION["trimColour"], $_SESSION["filling"], $_SESSION["wording"],
$_SESSION["cakePhoto"], $_SESSION["price"], $_SESSION["photo"] );

<input type="hidden" name="sd" value="<?php  echo $cart?>">
```

Then in my script I tried:

$result = $_POST['sd'];
echo $result[0];

to test it

but the remote call just passed the value as "Array" so echo $result[0] just returned "A", the values was just passed as Array and none of the values in the array got passed with it.

So now I'm trying to store all my session variables in the sd value like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sd" value="<?php  foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val) {  echo $val;}?>">
```

and then I tested it by doing on my script:

```
$result = $_POST['sd'];
echo $result;
```

Now this does pass all the values but obviously just as one big value, is there a way I can split them up? Is there a better way with the array I haven't thought of? Any advice would be greatly appreciated because I'm at a complete loss

Edit:

Forgot to add this part:

So after the array has been split I would need to stored the values separately so something like:

$name = first value
$email = second value etc

Comment: The duplicate has many good ways of achieving this result.

Comment: I've added more because what I need is not a duplicate I don't think, I know how get values over, I then need to be able to store them separately again

Comment: If you use (for example) the `json_encode` method from the second answer, you can then just use `json_decode` to recreate your original `$cart` array. Personally I would use an associative array to make it easier to get the values back out e.g. `$cart =array('date' => $_SESSION["date"], 'name' => $_SESSION["name"], 'email' => $_SESSION["email"], ...);`

Comment: okay thanks I'll try that

Comment: Hi, just want to say using the json encode and decode has worked perfectly, thanks for the advice! Massive relief to get this working

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `<input type="hidden" name="sd" value="<?php  echo $cart?`> to

```
<input type="hidden" name="sd[]" value="<?php  echo $cart?>
```

or use `serialize()` then `unserialize()` the result.

Refer to [Passing an array using an HTML form hidden element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-an-array-using-an-html-form-hidden-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `implode` and `explode` function.
The first part is implode.
We use `;` as implode delimeter which joins array elements as single string using that delimeter.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sd" value="<?php  foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val) {  echo $val.';';}?>">
```

Explode converts that string to array again using the delimeter we passed.

```
foreach (explode(';', $_REQUEST["sd"]) as $key) {
        echo $key;
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

**Update :**  Try This

```
<input type="hidden" name="sd" value="<?php  foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val) {  echo $key.';'.$val.';;';}?>">
```

Explode converts that string to array again using the delimeter we passed.

```
foreach (explode(';;', $_REQUEST["sd"]) as $key) {
        echo explode(';', $key)[0];
        echo " = " ;
        echo explode(';', $key)[1];
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: thank you, I think maybe I didn't word my question great, is there way I could do something like after explode function $name = the first value, $email = the second value and so on?

Comment: @LewisRoss see the updated answer

Comment: is there a way to actually store these values? so as in like for this part  echo explode(';', $key)[1]; is it possible to store these values separately, so get the first $key[1] value and store it in $name, get the second $key[1] value and store it in $email and so on?